# How to access the windows subsystem for linux 2 filesystem from another computer?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I know that I can access the wsl2 filesystem by just opening `\\wsl$` on the local computer. Can I somehow expose this to another computer in the same network? The goal is to just have a network drive on a remote computer where I drop files to copy them directly to wsl2.

EDIT: While it is not exactly what I wanted, I just noticed I can run a FTP server inside wsl2 and just transfer files in and out that way. I am still leaving the question open though as there might be a simpler solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your home folder of wsl on c drive (its in AppData) and use ordinary windows folder sharing.

Comment: But in WSL2 there is only a virtual hdd (.vhdx) in this location. And that can not be mounted while WSL is running.

Comment: @Maximilian, Sorry, you are right. My proposition is valid only for wsl1.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your network storage directly into WSL like in a particular Linux.

Example for Ubuntu and SMB: https://askubuntu.com/a/1050499